# If someone steals my goods/harms me then is it ok to take revenge on him/her?

Tags: karma

If someone has done some big bad thing bad to me, which can't be forgotten easily, then is it ok to take revenge on them, if that person is guilty in this matter?  Will it generate any negative karmic impression in me? should it? Which is important: peace or justice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the opening verses of the Dhammapada, for example, make it clear that "revenge" is not a way to appease emnity; and that "the wise" would "cease their quarrels" instead.

> 3. "He abused me, he ill-treated me, he got the better of me, he stole my belongings;"... the enmity of those harbouring such thoughts cannot be appeased.
> 4. "He abused me, he ill-treated me, he got the better of me, he stole my belongings;"... the enmity of those not harbouring such thoughts can be appeased.
> 5. Hatred is, indeed, never appeased by hatred in this world. It is appeased only by loving-kindness. This is an ancient law.
> 6. People, other than the wise, do not realize, "We in this world must all die," (and, not realizing it, continue their quarrels). The wise realize it and thereby their quarrels cease.

The problem seems to arise with the initial thought, "someone has done some big bad thing to me". I think that's the kind of problem which the doctrines of *anatta* and *[averena](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8735/254)* are meant to help solve.

Comment: this is wonderful quotes from buddha.

Comment: The [Dhammapada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhammapada) is a popular introduction or summary of doctrine. You can read it all [here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.intro.budd.html); or [here](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/) is a slightly more literal translation (and includes a story/commentary for each verse).

Answer (score 2):

Justice can be performed peacefully; without anger & violence. Simply use the police.

Answer (score 2):

No. 
Consider the phrase "revenge is like a boomarang, it just keeps coming back"

In fact from a karmic view point revenge is just ensuring you will experience like in the future.

Comment: Yes the back story to [verse 5](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=005) is of a feud continued over lifetimes.